# Android: Extending CardView which content can be expanded

Tags: java, android, xml, android-custom-view, android-cardview

I extended the android CardView to a Expandable version of it, with a header title and an icon which can be rotated.

**CODE**

This file(view_cardview_header.xml) contains the header of the ExpandableCardView, it should be the first child and not collapsed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The attrs.xml file with custom xml parameters

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ExpandableCardView">
        <attr name="expanded" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="headerTitle" format="string" />
        <attr name="headerIcon" format="integer" />
     </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

The ExpandableCardView.java class

```
public class ExpandableCardView extends CardView {

    private static final float ROTATION_NORMAL = 0.0f;
    private static final float ROTATION_ROTATED = 180f;
    private static final float PIVOT_VALUE = 0.5f;
    private static final long ROTATE_DURATION = 200;

    private boolean isExpanded;

    public ExpandableCardView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ExpandableCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ExpandableCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.ExpandableCardView, 0, 0);

        String titleText = a.getString(R.styleable.ExpandableCardView_headerTitle);
        final Drawable drawable = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.ExpandableCardView_headerIcon);

        a.recycle();

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_cardview_header, this, true);

        final LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);

        final RelativeLayout header = (RelativeLayout) parent.getChildAt(0);

        final TextView titleTextView = (TextView) header.getChildAt(0);
        titleTextView.setText(titleText);

        final ImageView toggle = (ImageView) header.getChildAt(1);
        if(drawable != null) {
            toggle.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        }

        header.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setExpanded(toggle, !isExpanded);
                onExpansionToggled(toggle);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if(getChildAt(0) == null || getChildAt(0).equals(child)) {
            super.addView(child, index, params);
        } else {
            ((LinearLayout) getChildAt(0)).addView(child);
        }
    }

    private void setExpanded(ImageView toggle, boolean expanded) {
        isExpanded = expanded;

        final LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) getChildAt(0);
        final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
        if(expanded) {
            toggle.setRotation(ROTATION_ROTATED);
            for(int i = childCount - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                parent.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            toggle.setRotation(ROTATION_NORMAL);
            for(int i = 1; i < childCount; i++) {
                parent.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void onExpansionToggled(ImageView toggle) {
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(ROTATION_ROTATED, ROTATION_NORMAL,
                RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, PIVOT_VALUE, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                PIVOT_VALUE);
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(ROTATE_DURATION);
        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        toggle.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    }
}
```

Fragment Layout for testing the new CardView(fragment_test.xml)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.tecdroid.views.ExpandableCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin"

        app:headerTitle="TITLE"
        app:headerIcon="@mipmap/ic_action_expand">

        <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First inner child"/>



    </com.tecdroid.views.ExpandableCardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[Result on Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpcYm.png)

**PROBLEM**

As you can see on the image, the first inner child(TextView), is not placed under the Relative Layout(Header).

First i thought i have to override the onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) method, but the ExpandableCardView extends indirect the ViewGroup, where the onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) method does it all for me.

Maybe someone figure out what i have forgot, or did wrong.

**UPDATE**
Problem solved, see changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CardView extends FrameLayout, your header and first child are just unrelated child views. To have a spatial relation between children you need to use a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout with align-* parameters.

Comment: Nice thank you, i forgot, that i everytime inserted a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout as first child in the normal CardView :D could i set the parent for the children in the CardView as an LinearLayout or do i have everytime to insert a LinearLayout inside my CardView as an parent?

Comment: Now i added a LinearLayout as parent and override the addView(...) method from the ExpandableCardView, where each child which is not the header RelativeLayout will be added to the LinearLayout, now it works, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

why not make a compound view with your cardview and a layout of your choice that contains the child view?